# updating firebase with values retrieved shows error Reference.child failed error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, reference

Im trying to update firebase values retrieved but I receive an error : Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"  firebase.js:324:31719, not sure whats causing this problem.

Here is the code :

```
var ref=firebase.database().ref("REGISTRATION");
var key;

function callUpdateFunction(){
var email,name, gender, birthdate, phone, state, school, clas, classname;
    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    birthdate = document.getElementById("birthdate").value;
    phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    school = document.getElementById("school").value;
    clas = document.getElementById("clas").value;
    classname = document.getElementById("classname").value;

    var dataUpdate={};

    dataUpdate.name = name;
    dataUpdate.email = email;
    dataUpdate.gender = gender;
    dataUpdate.birthdate = birthdate;
    dataUpdate.phone = phone;
    dataUpdate.state = state;
    dataUpdate.school = school;
    dataUpdate.class = clas;
    dataUpdate.classname = classname;
```

In the browser console window I get an error in at this point

```
ref.child(key).set(dataUpdate).then(function()
{

    init();

    document.getElementById("EditContent").style.display="none";
})
}
```

Comment: hi, man, can you please put a debugger near dataUpdate and place your mouse over it and update the question with a screenshot and also key value is undefined or empty?.

Comment: Hey man are you there?

Comment: Sorry cant add images based on my reputation so uploaded here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izy7R.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bkLU.png | 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrfXt.png ALSO DEBUGGER SHOWS NO DATA ON MOUSE OVER, WHILE ALL OTHER KEYS HAVE VALUES IN THEM.

Comment: try "update" instead of "set" in the query like "ref.child(key).update(dataUpdate)"

Comment: Tried ref.child(key).update(dataUpdate).then(function() same reference error..

Comment: update my jsfiddle with your code and ping me, man.

Comment: Updated in JSFiddle...

Comment: give me the link man

Comment: Sorry : https://jsfiddle.net/s1asyx1j/9/

Comment: I have updated the js fiddle and posted the answer.

Comment: Its not working on my end...nothing happens after clicking update, not sure what the issue would, I will wait and recheck after some time, Thanks again as my internet is slow momentarily, Thanks again for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsfiddle key row is actually 10 but you have given 9 so the key value is empty string, your code is

```
$('#append tr').find('td:eq(10)').hide(); //your hiding your key as td:eq(10) but in your get value you took 9's value.

 key = $(this).find('td:eq(9)').map(function () {return $(this).text();}).get().join(" ");
```

So change it to 10 and try to update your data.

[See the updated js fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/s1asyx1j/11/)

Comment: Its up now, working great, much appreciated your help, I will make sure my upvote counts once I have 15 reputations, Have a nice day :)

Comment: Hey, just a quick question, how can I make the edit table refresh from the form page after adding data to fire base, I have to refresh manually to view new added data, I have tried several commands in Javascript and JQuery, window.reload, window.location, .load from JQuery but they dont work, earlier I used to use child_added and it would fetch data automatically but since in your code there is no child_added, unsure on how to do it..

Comment: again call init() methodf once you add data to the firebase

Comment: Hi, the init function is called when the edit function (both of which are on the same page) is called but I am adding data from another form and then I add init it doesnt call the function, nothing happens..